# What is a naked singularity?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, causality, singularities

What is a [naked singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naked_singularity)? Would a naked singularity be one that that the event horizon is so small that it is the same size as the singularity?   what could make one that small?

Answer (score 1):

A naked singularity is a singularity that is not covered by an event horizon at all. That makes the singularity visible to the other parts of the world. In an ordinary black hole there are interior and exterior regions separated by the horizon. An object that goes through the horizon is doomed to pass it thoroughly never to come back to the exterior region it was in previously. Without a horizon there is no interior region which makes it possible for objects to have access to the singularity.
As an example, in Reissner–Nordström geometry if the amount of charge surpasses that of mass, there will be no real solutions for event horizons and the singularity will therefore be naked.